API being Cached
Im trying to access the API for the first time, specifically for this endpoint :
https://public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/skillsFramework/jobRoles/titles
It seems that the results are being cached, both at postman as well as using my own python script.
Here is some code that i wrote, with the Api key being hidden
import requests


def get_job_roles(api_key, keyword=None, page_number=1, page_size=10, sort_order='asc', no_cache=False):
    url = "https://public-api.ssg-wsg.sg/skillsFramework/jobRoles/titles"
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache" 
    }
    params = {
        "pageNumber": page_number,
        "pageSize": page_size,
        "sortOrder": sort_order
    }
    if keyword:
        params['keyword'] = keyword
    
    if no_cache:
        params['_'] = requests.utils.quote(str(time.time()))  # Dummy parameter to bypass cache

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()  # Return the JSON response if successful
    else:
        return response.status_code, response.text  # Return error code and message if not successful

import time  # Importing time module to use current time as dummy parameter

# Replace 'your_api_key_here' with your actual API key
api_key = 'yourapikey'
result = get_job_roles(api_key, keyword="Senior Manager", no_cache=True)
print(result)


Any help is much appreciated
I tried intially to search for the keyword "Engineer" and it returned results correctly.
After that any changes to the keyword resulted in the exact same results in both python as well Postman
